# NullPointerException when adding ClickListener

Tags: android, exception, android-intent, nullpointerexception

I try to find a view by its ID but I get the `NullPointerException`. Have you any idea where am I doing wrong?

**This is the exception I'm getting**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.voicemail, PID: 24209
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.voicemail/com.example.voicemail.ComposeMail}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3162)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3305)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1993)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7285)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:975)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.voicemail.ComposeMail.onCreate(ComposeMail.java:34)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7353)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7344)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1275)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3142)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3305) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1993) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7285) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:975)
```

**The code:**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Initializing the views
    editTextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);

    editTextSubject = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextSubject);

    editTextMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextMessage);

    buttonSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSend);

    buttonSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            sendEmail();
        }
    });
}

private void sendEmail() {
   //doSomething
}
```

**Here's my XML code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/bg2"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    tools:context=".ComposeMail">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:textColorHint="@android:color/white"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:hint="@string/to"

        android:id="@+id/editTextEmail" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:textColorHint="@android:color/white"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:hint="@string/subject"
        android:id="@+id/editTextSubject" />

    <EditText
        android:lines="15"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textColorHint="@android:color/white"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:hint="@string/message"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:id="@+id/editTextMessage" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonSend"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/round_corner"
        android:text="@string/send"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I'm getting a `NullPointerException` on `setOnClickListener`. Basically I'm sending data from one activity to another using an intent. I have tried almost everything to solve this but it keeps on showing me the same exception. Please help me.

Comment: Please paste your `onCreate` Method & `XML` code.

Comment: We'll need to see the XML. Probably you have no button with id buttonSend.

Comment: Added onCreate method and XML code!

Comment: Everything is a good try to **`clean & Rebuild`** your project & check again. Also remove this line from xml `tools:context=".ComposeMail"` @MuskanKadakia

Comment: Still didn't work out :( I'm getting the same exception @Ali

Comment: How to declare buttonSend in java file can you please show me @MuskanKadakia

Comment: private Button buttonSend; @Ali

Comment: try renaming the button id, it create a new entry in R file which might fix the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not calling an appropriate design layout. Please add **`setContentView(R.layout.ComposeMail);`** instead of     **`setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`** in your class. Your class must call the appropriate design layout.

Comment: Thank you so much! @Ali I had made a mistake in the XML file only, it should've been activity_compose according to my project. Thanks for helping!

Comment: Although after resolving this exception, I got three more null pointer exceptions. Could you help me with that if it's possible? @Ali

Comment: Sure paste new question or either join this group: **[android-kotlin-experts](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50272/android-kotlin-experts)** @MuskanKadakia

Comment: It says "You must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk here. See the faq" and I'm a new user @Ali

Comment: Please paste the new question in SO @MuskanKadakia

Comment: I'm not being able to chat there, I have less reps. So I'll just upload the next question you could help me there maybe? @Ali

Comment: @MuskanKadakia Sure please share me link.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60279904/nullpointer-exception-on-class - here's the link! @Ali

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I think it will work.

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

EditText editTextEmail, editTextSubject, editTextMessage;
Button buttonSend;

//Initializing the views
editTextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
editTextSubject = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextSubject);
editTextMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextMessage);



buttonSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSend);
buttonSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        sendEmail();
    }
});

private void sendEmail() {

    //Getting content for email
    String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
    String subject = editTextSubject.getText().toString().trim();
    String message = editTextMessage.getText().toString().trim();
    String e=intent.getStringExtra("Username");
    String p=intent.getStringExtra("Password");

    //Creating SendMail object
    SendMail sm = new SendMail(this, email, subject, message, e, p);
}
```